# Combine two dataframes by row (irrespective of columns names)

Tags: r

this seems to be pretty simple.

My goal is to just combine these two dataframes by row without using `r_bind` or `merge` since this would be dependent on my column names.

```
   obj <- data.frame (
      yr = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995),
      occ = c(223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228))
    
    obj1 <- data.frame (
      emp = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
      degree = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

The expected output would be:

```
 emp degree
1  10      1
2  10      1
3  10      1
4  10      1
5  10      1
6  10      1
1 1990    223
2 1991    224
3 1992    225
4 1993    226
5 1994    227
6 1995    228
```

many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Replace the column names of the obj with obj1 and use `rbind` i.e. `rbind(obj1, setNames(obj, names(obj1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option is `list2DF` + `Map`

```
> list2DF(Map(c, obj1, obj))
    emp degree
1    10      1
2    10      1
3    10      1
4    10      1
5    10      1
6    10      1
7  1990    223
8  1991    224
9  1992    225
10 1993    226
11 1994    227
12 1995    228
```

---

Also, you can try `rbindlist` from `data.table` package

```
data.table::rbindlist(list(obj1, obj), use.names = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
     emp degree
 1:   10      1
 2:   10      1
 3:   10      1
 4:   10      1
 5:   10      1
 6:   10      1
 7: 1990    223
 8: 1991    224
 9: 1992    225
10: 1993    226
11: 1994    227
12: 1995    228
```

Comment: @akrun Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out :)